# How do I use an HTML anchor tag with JS to change an IMG inside a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, image, anchor

I am trying to create a simple photography website.  I want to create a menu of links that will change the main IMG inside a DIV.  My idea was just to use the basic CSS menu style of `<UL><LI>` and have the `<LI>` items that call a JS function to change the HTML or the image itself.

I'm in Egypt right now with a horrible internet connection and I'm struggling to find previous tutorials online so I need help learning which tutorials to look for.

What would be the best way to make this work?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your question is too broad as is currently written. It isn't also much clear what you what to achieve exactly. And questions asking us to recommend or find a tutorial are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1):

you could hide the src of the images in the listitem's "data-src" property, and change the "main" image's src each time one is clicked.  Sample code:

```
<img id="imgToChange" src="BlahBlahBlah.jpg"/>

<ul>
    <li class="ImageChanger" data-src="~/RelativePath/AnotherImage.jpg">Click me!</li>
</ul>
```

jquery (modify for regular javascript if you want):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(".ImageChanger").on("click", function(){
        $("#imgToChange").prop("src", $(this).data("src"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set each 'a' element with the id of the image name, you can use this id to set the image url of the main DIV element.

I first use the .click function on the 'a' element. I use event.target.id to retrieve the id from the 'a' element. I grab the main DIV with #img. I use .css to set the background-image, and the id to set the url.

```js
(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(event){
    var id = (event.target.id);
    $('#img').css("background-image", 'url(' + id + '.png)');
  })
}
```

```css
#img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div id="img">
  
  </div>

  <ul>
   <l><i></i><a href="#" id="img-1">Image 1</a></l>
   <l><i></i><a href="#" id="img-2">Image 2</a></l>
   <l><i></i><a href="#" id="img-3">Image 3</a></l>
  </ul>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typically you wouldn't want to bind to all `a` elements if you know specifically which ones would be changing the image.